# How do I select similar-contented items in multiple lists when any one is selected?

Tags: jquery-ui, list

I am using HTML4.01 Strict, CSS3 and the latest JQuery.

I have three identical lists in one page - one acts as a menu bar, the other two are smaller and appear on either side of the main page content.

I would like it so that when any single option in one list is selected, it also selects the same option in the other two lists.

'Selection' in this case means the application of the class "active_tab" [via `.addClass("active_tab")` ]

The list:

```
<ul id="lt-menu" class="shift_menu">
    <li class="li_tab">Home</li>
    <li class="li_tab">News</li>
    <li class="li_tab">Info</li>
    <li class="li_tab">Download</li>
    <li class="li_tab">Contact</li>
    <li class="li_tab">Shop</li>
</ul>
```

I have been attempting to use something along these lines -

```
$(".tab, .li_tab").click(function() {
    $(".active_tab").removeClass("active_tab");
    $("li".contains(this)).addClass("active_tab");
});
```

But with no luck so far.

I'm pretty new to JQuery, so any help at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Il tried this with 3 copies of your list (I just change the ID), and it works:

```
$(".tab, .li_tab").click(function() {
    //Disable current selection
    $(".active_tab").removeClass("active_tab");

    // We get the index of the <li> in the current list
    // Each <li> has to be to the same index in the other lists
    var index = $(this).index();

    // We add the 'active_tab' class to all <li> with the same index
    // Assume that all lists have the 'shift_menu' class, of modify the selector
    $('.shift_menu').find('li:eq(' + index + ')').addClass("active_tab");
});
```

Hope it works for you...